# What does iw command mean in vim surround plugin

Tags: vim

Hello w*orld!             ysiw)       Hello (world)!

What does the

> iw

part of the command mean?

Comment: Answer at `:help iw`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`iw` means inside word - the entire command reads "yank surround inside word".

Answer (score 4):

```
iw
```

doesn't mean anything in the surround plugin. In Vim, however, it is one of the many awesome text-objects/motions available by default.

`:help motion.txt` will blow your mind.

You should probably invest a bit more time into learning the basics before installing plugins.

Comment: Wow that's fantastic! I'm gotta dig deeper about Vim